# What if a seasonal naive model is the best model?

Tags: r, time-series, interpretation, mape

I ran 10 years worth of monthly data (first 7 years train, next 3 test), through 8 forecasting algorithms:

- SARIMA, ETS, HW, Seasonal Naive, NNETAR, Prophet, TBATS, and VAR.

For most of these, where there was an option to automatically tune a parameter I took it, the reason is that I am dealing with 10 separate time series.

The results were somewhat disappointing. I think I wanted one of the more complex models to win out, but it didn't happen.

Does this happen in practice often? Should I be concerned? Below are my MAPE scores for each of the 8 models. Note that this MAPE score was the mean MAPE of the 10 time series. Naive wins by a small margin.

[image: MAPE scores]

Comment: It's an interesting question. Have you looked at how the MAPE changes if you extend the forecast horizon?